# Magento 1.9.0.1 add a product to the cart by URL?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am currently using Magento 1.9.0.1.

I want to add a product to the cart by URL execution.

I am trying the solutions pointed here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring but none of them works.

Any ideas how i can make it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there have also comment see. As of version 1.3.X, it appears that adding a product to the cart by a URL no longer works.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do this on a CMS page, here's a simple approach:

On the CMS page, add the following content:

```
<a href="/checkout/cart/add?product=<product_id>&qty=<qty>&form_key={{block type="core/template" name="getformkey" template="getformkey.phtml"}}">Add to cart</a>
```

(Replace `<product_id>` and `<qty>` with the desired values.)

Now create a new template to at *app/design/package/theme/template/getformkey.phtml*:

```
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
```

Your CMS page will now be able to create an "Add to cart" link with the correct form key in the front-end, for example:

```
/checkout/cart/add?product=1234&qty=10&form_key=crtH4Ol3DYNeSFr5
```

Comment: I added the product to cart and it worked. However, I tried to add the product again and it does not add to cart. The Form Key is the same. After I flush cache storage, the form key changes than I can add to cart successfully. How can we change the form without flushig storage cache?

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if you try to add the product twice via the same URL. Perhaps a better solution would be to set the quantity to "2" when first adding it?

Comment: Why 2? Its working now. However, I see it now working. When I clear storage cache, the form key changes.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer of @louis-b I used it in php which works. You can use this as href of with setLocation in javascript.

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add', array('product'=>$_item->getId(),'qty'=>1, 'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Magento 1.8 you need to include a form_key along with the post.

Inside your php call the following to retrieve the form key:

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();`

Answer (score 2):

Tried This?

```
<?php

$formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>

<form action="/checkout/cart/add/product/<?php echo $productid; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />

    <input type="text" name="qty"> QTY

    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
</form>
```

Comment: If it's for a template you can use `echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')` to output a whole hidden input element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" >

```
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
      </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="<?php echo$this->_getUrl('checkout/cart/add', $routeParams) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

 <input name="qty" value="  1" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" id="cart[<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>][qty]"/>


                     <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add+')) ?>" onclick="this.form.submit()" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add+') ?></span></span></button>

</form>

 $routeParams = array(
            /*Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->_getHelperInstance('core')
       $routeParams = array(       
            Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey()
        );


<?php  

?>
```

Comment: Some explanation of your answer would be helpful.