# Adding products to cart on the click of a banner

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ce-1.9.2.4

I want to add a product to the cart on the click of a banner. I referred to the fourth answer on this link - [Magento 1.9.0.1 add a product to the cart by URL?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28893/magento-1-9-0-1-add-a-product-to-the-cart-by-url)

But on following the steps as stated, I am getting this error - **The requested URL /checkout/cart/add was not found on this server**. Can't understand what's wrong.

Would also like to know if there is any alternative approach to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this and it works perfectly. All you need are these couple of lines.

```
<?php $url = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>
<script>
    setLocation('<?php echo $url; ?>');
</script>
```

---

Here is a very basic, yet fully functional example.

1. Navigave to CMS > Pages in the admin panel and click on your homepage so that the edit screen opens up.
2. Click on the 'Design' tab, and in the fieldset up top named 'Layout Update XML', add this snippet to it and click save:

   ```
   <reference name="before_body_end">
       <block type="core/template" name="custom_banner_js" template="custom/banner/js.phtml"/>
   </reference>
   ```
3. Then create this file: app/design/frontend/rwd/astraboot‌/template/custom/banner/js.phtml
4. In your newly created file, here is the full content to paste into it:

   ```
   <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(39); ?>
   <?php $url = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>
   <script>
       var myImage = $('subscription_product');
       myImage.observe('click',function(){
           setLocation('<?php echo $url; ?>');
       });
   </script>
   ```
5. Save your file
6. Clear your cache
7. Refresh the page
8. Test!

Keep in mind, that if you did not remove the `<a>` tag that was wrapped around the image, this wont work, so just be certain that you removed it.

Comment: I should also mention that you will want to add an event listener for clicks on your banner before invoking setLocation($url) but if you want to test this example, will work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Shawn Abramson for your efforts, but since I'm a beginner, can you please tell me which files do I need to edit for the above codes.

Comment: This code can go into many of the different phtml files. How are you adding the banner to your site? With a CMS static block or in one of the template files?

Comment: And also, which pages on your site contain the banner?

Comment: I am using a CMS static block which was already present in the theme I had installed

Comment: Ok and two other pieces of info I would need are: What is the product ID that you want to add to the cart? And what is the html ID of the banner people would click?

Comment: The banner in which I intend to use is in the home page

Comment: The product id is 39 and I couldn't get what you meant by html id.

Comment: The code in the static cms block is this - <div class="promo-banner-section container wow bounceInUp animated">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="/checkout/cart/add?product=39&amp;qty=1&amp;form_key={{block type="core/template" name="getformkey" template="getformkey.phtml"}}"><img alt="promo-banner1" src="{{skin url="images/promo-banner1.png"}}" /></a></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img alt="promo-banner2" src="{{skin url="images/promo-banner2.png"}}" /></div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: The banner is most likely an html element that starts with `<img .... src="path/to/image.jpg"/>` or something similar. Look within that image tag and see if there is an id="something"

Comment: There isn't any id ="something" within the image tag

Comment: Your image does not have an id, you should give it one. Change `<img alt="promo-banner1" src="{{skin url=" images/promo-banner1.png"}}" />` to `<img alt="promo-banner1" id="some-unique-string" src="{{skin url=" images/promo-banner1.png"}}" />

Comment: I see that, please see my comment above. You can easily add one and name it anything you want. Then also, remove the link around the image. That is, the part that begins with `<a ... >` and then its closing tag `</a>`

Comment: Once you do that, Im gonna give you the step by step. It should be a piece of cake

Comment: Changed the code as you mentioned

Comment: ok, gimme a few mins and im going to update my answer. Btw, whats the path to your theme files? For example, if you are using rwd/default, the path is `app/design/frontend/rwd/default`

Comment: This is the path -  C:\wamp\www\astrabootstrap\app\design\frontend\rwd\astrabootstrap

Comment: What was the ID that you gave to your image?

Comment: id = subscription_product

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. It's working perfect. Thanks a ton!

Comment: you are welcome, my pleasure!

Comment: Also, how should I add this code to other pages rather than the home page. Like, I want to add the above functionality to this page - http://jainculture.pavaiyacart.com/pooja-thali-set-1.html at one of the images on the right side